# GLSL Editor program

Tags: opengl, editor, glsl

I'm looking for a GLSL editor program. I did find some by googling, but I wanna know if there are any preferred ones based on user experience.

**Possible** features:

- Syntax Highlighting
- Intellisense
- Automatic compile and link

P.S.
I'm not even sure if it's meaningful/possible for GLSL to be compiled automatically (any comments?).

**EDIT:**
Here's what I found:

- [Shader Maker](http://cgvr.cs.uni-bremen.de/teaching/shader_maker/)

Comment: What version of GLSL do you have en mind? And is it for WebGL,OpenGL ES or OpenGL?

Comment: @Mortennobel: GLSL 330, and it's OpenGL.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an editor program? Do you mean something that has some syntax highlighting, or a full-fledged IDE for GLSL?

Comment: @NicolBolas: edited post. I added possible features. Not all of them are necessary.

Comment: Could you please precise the editors you usually code with as there may be some plugins?

Comment: @elenfoiro78 At the time I used Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

Try out KickJS's Shader Editor. It currently supports syntax highlight and compiles the code as you write.

http://www.kickjs.org/example/shader_editor/shader_editor.html

If you are running OS/X you should try out the OpenGL Shader Builder, even though this tool feels a little out-dated:

/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools/OpenGL Shader Builder.app

There is also the GLman, which maybe is more a GLSL sandbox environment than a editor. A good introduction to the program is found in the excellent book: 'Graphics Shaders - Theory and practice - Second edition'.

http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mjb/glman/

Comment: Thanks, I think KickJS is used for WebGL, right? However I could still use the syntax highlighting feature. But, I'm wondering if there's a downloadable version?

Comment: Yes KickJS is written for WebGL, so the GLSL is mainly for WebGL or OpenGL ES 2.0. If you use OpenGl 4.1 or higher the shaders should also run. It should be fairly easy to migrate shader code between different version of GLSL. The hard part is to implement the shader :)

Comment: Thanks for introducing KickJS, I never heard of it before, it looks very promising with apparently more features than ShaderToy (but feels less "social-oriented" though).

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently working on the next version with support for error messages displayed at the margin of the text editor (like other IDEs). Expected time of arrival is middle of March.

Comment: can I download the editor on this phone and transfer it to my offline development machine?? (I currently don't have internet)

Answer (score 2):

I found **shader toy** to be helpful. Contains some predefined shaders you can tweak and see instant results. All online and covers WebGL, OpenGL ES 1.1 / (some) 2.0, probably OpenGL various versions too.

https://www.shadertoy.com/

It passes in some predefined uniforms as well as up to 4 textures you can hyperlink too.

*Here are the following inputs:*

- uniform vec4 mouse: xy contain the current pixel coords (if LMB is down). zw contain the click pixel.
- uniform vec2 resolution: the rendering vieport resolution.
- uniform float time: current time in seconds.
- uniform sampler2D tex0: sampler for input texture 0.
- uniform sampler2D tex1: sampler for input texture 1.
- uniform sampler2D tex2: sampler for input texture 2.
- uniform sampler2D tex3: sampler for input texture 3.

Answer (score 1):

I've found http://glsl.heroku.com interesting, you can edit only the fragment shader, but it's quite useful for testing some effects.

And it's open source! You can get the source on github: https://github.com/mrdoob/glsl-sandbox

Example of a shader using this editor: http://glsl.heroku.com/e#7310.0 (it's not mine, btw)